# How to ALLOW access to a specific path only from within a namespace in istio/k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have an application running on K8s/istio in `foo` namespace. I don't have any Authorization Policy and everything works as expected. Now I want to ALLOW access to a specific path only from within `bar` namespace. So I created an AuthorizationPolicy as follow:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-specific-path
  namespace: foo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  action: DENY
  rules:
    - to:
      - operation:
          paths: ["/specific/path/*"]
    - from:
      - source:
          notNamespaces: ["bar"]
```

My understanding is the above AP should only allow access to `/specific/path/*` path from `bar` namespace. Any other path access should not get affected and work as before. But this causes other paths in my application to be denied including accessing home page `/home` of the app. What is wrong here? appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding is the above AP should only allow access to /specific/path/* path from bar namespace.

This is not correct, because of the list of elements in your `rules` section. You have two rules here.

```
  rules:
    - to:
      - operation:
          paths: ["/specific/path/*"]
    - from:
      - source:
          notNamespaces: ["bar"]
```

The first rule applies to requests targeting `/specific/path/*` and the second rule applies to requests coming from anywhere except the `bar` namespace.

Each element in a list or `rules` is OR'd together. It sounds like you want to AND these two rules together, so try removing the `-` from the second one (making it into one rule with a `from` and `to` clause).